# How to fix a Java VM missing class

Tags: java, openfire

I am getting this error when trying to run OpenFire on the jamVM Java Virtual Machine

java.util.jar.Pack200 not found in java.lang.ClassLoader

We have found the Pack200 jar file, but don't understand how to add it to the Java VM

Comment: Ref. [CLASSPATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java))

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the jarfile is on your [classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).